# User profiles for ESXi

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I have configured active directory with my ESXi Server and all is great. I created User Profiles for this experiment within Windows 2008r2. Logged in with a windows 7 VM within Vsphere, and all works.

My suspicions solely believe that Vsphere is just a management console for the ESXi Server. Or am I wrong? However I really am interested to know some peoples opinions please?

1. Upon logging in with x,y,z user they all can see every single VM that is running/shutdown etc. Is there a possible way to separate users so when they log into Vsphere they can only see the VM's they have created, and not have access to the any other users VM's.
2. If Vsphere is JUST a management console, what solution can anyone suggest that will help me achieve my goal?

Comment: What is your goal exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, please read the VMware docs available [here](https://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/) and [here](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55). Your question clearly shows that you didn't read it at all.

vCenter is how you manage ESXi Servers professionally in a multi-ESXi-host environment, it provides lots of [features](http://www.vmware.com/products/vcenter-server/features) like host profiles, VM and Host Management via a web client, powerful scripting API, inventory etc.

On to your question:

Beside other options like centalized users/groups via Active Directory or LDAP, the box you installed vCenter on may be used as a user account store for vCenter. Roles and permissions are managed inside the application though.

This means that you have to log on to vCenter via Webclient or the vSphere client and create roles, assign them permissions and then assign those roles (or the predefined ones) to entities within the vCenter inventory (folders, clusters, hosts, VMs, datastores, etc.)

For details, see the VMware docs here: https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.security.doc/GUID-93B962A7-93FA-4E96-B68F-AE66D3D6C663.html?resultof="roles"%20"role"%20

Comment: Thanks for the constructive criticism!! :) I have learnt AD how to connect ESXi and authenticate users with it within 4 days! Give me some slack please! What I have know found the answer is yes I can basically! Just been looking at the permissions what I want to achieve.